# matplotlib: values for the (xx-small, x-small, small, medium, large, x-large, xx-large, larger, smaller) special sizes

Tags: python, matplotlib

The [`matplotlibrc`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#a-sample-matplotlibrc-file) sample file states that:

```
## The font.size property is the default font size for text, given in pts.
## 10 pt is the standard value.
##
## Note that font.size controls default text sizes.  To configure
## special text sizes tick labels, axes, labels, title, etc, see the rc
## settings for axes and ticks.  Special text sizes can be defined
## relative to font.size, using the following values: xx-small, x-small,
## small, medium, large, x-large, xx-large, larger, or smaller
```

What are the equivalent values in pts for those "special text sizes"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can also compute the absolute font sizes yourself very easily

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

t = ax.text(0.5, 0.5, 'Text')

fonts = ['xx-small', 'x-small', 'small', 'medium', 'large', 
         'x-large', 'xx-large', 'larger', 'smaller']

for font in fonts:
    t.set_fontsize(font)
    print (font, round(t.get_fontsize(), 2))

plt.close()
```

**Output**

```
xx-small 5.79
x-small 6.94
small 8.33
medium 10.0
large 12.0
x-large 14.4
xx-large 17.28
larger 12.0
smaller 8.33
```

Answer (score 12):

I think these are scaling as in relative sizing, see documentation/code [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/font_manager_api.html#matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties) and [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.5.1/lib/matplotlib/font_manager.py#L51-L62):

> size: Either an relative value of 'xx-small', 'x-small', 'small',
> 'medium', 'large', 'x-large', 'xx-large' or an absolute font size,
> e.g., 12

```
font_scalings = {
    'xx-small' : 0.579,
    'x-small'  : 0.694,
    'small'    : 0.833,
    'medium'   : 1.0,
    'large'    : 1.200,
    'x-large'  : 1.440,
    'xx-large' : 1.728,
    'larger'   : 1.2,
    'smaller'  : 0.833,
    None       : 1.0}
```